# Register application to start on system event

Tags: windows, service, driver

I have a windows service. I also develop a driver for a device.
I want my service to start only when the device is plugged in.

I thought that maybe I can somehow start the service from the driver, but after googling it, I understood that it is forbidden.

Is there any other way to start a service or an application from system event.

Comment: Why would this be forbidden? (Documentation?) I think windows does the same thing. Some services only start when needed.

Comment: @Rik I know that there are http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2009/08/15/introducing-device-services.aspx , that can be started from the inf file, but they are not regualr services

Answer (score 0):

The [StartService Function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) discusses conditions for starting a service, including discussions about when it cannot be used and how to check for that condition.  It specifically says that:

> When a driver service is started, the StartService function does not
>   return until the device driver has finished initializing.

So, you'd have to complete device initialization before issuing the StartService, but that should be possible?

Comment: Thanks! but is the driver service is a regular service? because from what I saw "A driver service conforms to the device driver protocols. It is similar to a service application, but it does not interact with the SCM"

Comment: In both your question and your comment, you quoted unreferenced sources.  This is true even after Rik asked you for that reference.  Please provide complete information so that people can provide helpful responses.  In particular, the reference I provided discusses the driver service's SCM interactions.  That driver service is relatively new, so your quote may be dated?

Answer (score 0):

What I am going to do is to register my application as a task in Task Scheduler, and set the trigger to event in the event log.

Then in my driver I will raise this specific event.

This way I can run an application from the driver.

Comment: I'm not going to say this won't work, but I wouldn't consider it reliable because there are simply too many "moving parts" that could break.  If it serves your purpose, that's good enough.